# Recorded a macro to change (blank) in pivot table to an empty cell. I get a 1004 error when running ExecuteExcel4Macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with a lot of (blank) in cells and I would rather them be just blank. I recorded a macro to hide this expression using conditional formatting. When I do it manually, it works but when I run the recorded macro it gets a 1004 error when it gets to the ExecuteExcel4Macro command.  Here's my recorded code with no edits:

```
    Range("H5:M17").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = ";;;"
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""(blank)"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "(2,1,"";;;"")"
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Here's the error:

[image: 1004 error]

I also think the second command (Selection.NumberFormat = ";;;") is superfluous, but left it in for now. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'd remove the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` line as it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks Rory, you get partial credit! - I posted the working code below.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into PivotTable Options? You might be able to avoid conditional formatting. Just look for the "For empty cells show:" box.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. that was my first avenue to solve this but the (blank) cells remain unchanged. I just verified it. That only works for the value settings and not for the row dimensions.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, remove the second line and change the Execute4Macro line to `Selection.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = ";;;"`

Comment: Bryan, we have a WINNNER!

Answer (score -1):

Bryan had the answer. Here's the working code:

```
    Range("H5:M17").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""(blank)"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = ";;;"
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```